# Simplifying this masm to make it faster?

Tags: c++, int, masm, addition

I am trying to make the c++ code of adding 512 bit (big int) converted into masm inline assembler in visual studio.
Carry is very important as the C++ shown in the link below.I do need to represent the c++ into masm inline assembler in visual studio

I tried to do this in masm but it is slow it took mearly 700 ms for my masm code

[C++ code Here](http://codepad.org/bMZHQKKL).
C++ Takes 300 ms for addition

Masm code

```
_asm {
         mov edx, summand
         mov eax, [edx]
         mov ebx, this
         add eax, [ebx]
         mov [ebx], eax
```

mov ecx, 4
     mov eax, [edx + ecx]
     adc eax, [ebx + ecx]
     mov [ebx + ecx], eax

     mov ecx, 8
     mov eax, [edx + ecx]
     adc eax, [ebx + ecx]
     mov [ebx + ecx], eax

     mov ecx, 12
     mov eax, [edx + ecx]
     adc eax, [ebx + ecx]
     mov [ebx + ecx], eax
  }

Comment: It would seem that your C++ compiler is better at writing code than you are. That's to be expected. Modern compilers perform heroic optimisations. Why do you expect to be able to do better? What code did your compiler emit? How did it differ? How confident are you in your timings?

Comment: Well c++ code is shown up in the link..time needed to do the operation is 100% sure for every addition either by c++ or by asm

Comment: The C++ code is not executed. The compiler generates the code that gets executed. What does that generated code looks like? And how did you time? So many benchmark questions here on SO turn out to be down to flawed timings.

Comment: timing is being calculated when there is 2 numbers of addition ,when the result is coming into the screen ,the timing stops...I dont want to share the project of mine since it is big project and paid too

Comment: Are you performing a lot of additions and dividing by the count? Or are you timing just one addition? It's much better if you do the former.

Comment: The timing is for the whole process of adding 2 numbers of 512 bits. numbers

Comment: well_i  will try to give u real program to check later on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80ccffx3.aspx

Comment: @TonyK: We need you to conduct yourself more professionally here. This is not the school yard.

Comment: @Lightness: If it's professionalism you want, just see my answer. I queried the 700ms there, but OP didn't bite. Now lighten up.

Comment: @TonyK: All caps is considered rude on the internet, and SO encourages us to act in a professional manner. Please consider doing so. Thank you.

Comment: @Lightness: I know what all caps means, thank you. My (professional) opinion was that OP needed shouting at, for their own good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably faster to use

```
 mov eax, [edx + 4]
 adc eax, [ebx + 4]
 mov [ebx + 4], eax
```

instead of

```
 mov ecx, 4
 mov eax, [edx + ecx]
 adc eax, [ebx + ecx]
 mov [ebx + ecx], eax
```

and the same for 8 and 12. But I would be surprised if your asm code is really slower than the C++ code in your link. It may be that using an asm block disables some optimisations in another part of the function. You will have to look at the generated assembler code for the whole function to find that out. (And what is your 700ms?)

Comment: Every Addition takes nearly 700 ms for every addition..This Never Change speed much ,just few mili seconds.

Comment: i don't know,but it is slow which makes my algorithm in masm useless since i can get better performance in c++.

Comment: @us2012: On the contrary, this is precisely the kind of problem for which in-line assembly is useful. C++ has no carry flag! Not only is it faster in assembly language, it can actually be simpler to write. (Have you looked at the C++ code?)

Comment: @TonyK You're right, I didn't look at the C++ at all. Deleted my comment.